# Display PHP variable value onchange of HTML dropdown option

Tags: php, html

I have 3 PHP Variable values with me which i want to display depending on the HTML option selected from the drop down menu without refreshing the page.

```html
<p>
<label for="package" class="formlbl">I want to Enroll In:</label>
    <select name="package" id="package">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="full_package">Complete Package</option>
    <option value="training">Only Training</option>
    <option value="counselling">Only Counselling</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

What i want is when he selects full package it should echo variable no 1, when he selects training it should echo variable no 2 and so on without refreshing the page.

Please tell me what i should do. The values and variable are working in the code.

Comment: You can't do an `echo` after an html event. What you can do is to use javascript do make a dynamic request (aka ajax) to a certain php script, and so this script processes and returns some data to the javascript, so, with data in hands, javascript can expose what you want to show to you users.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to create all the packages and set their display to none. Then use javascript to show the right package on the option select.

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is only a server-side language once the response is sent to the client, php can no longer change anything on the page without a refresh.

You will need to use javascript in order to have content that changes without reloading a new page (also called dynamic content). You can do this really easily with a framework called jquery.

Add jquery to your webpage with this html line:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and then use this html template for your dropdown:

```
<!-- make each item in your dropdown an <a> with an ID -->
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li onclick="toggleResponse('comp')">Complete </li>
    <li onclick="toggleResponse('pack')">Package Only </li>
    <li onclick="toggleResponse('train')">Training Only </li>
    <li onclick="toggleResponse('couns')">Counselling </li>
<ul>

<!-- give every response the same class, and individual IDs -->
<span class="response" id="comp"><?php echo var1 ?></span>
<span class="response" id="pack"><?php echo var2 ?></span>
<span class="response" id="train"><?php echo var3 ?></span>
<span class="response" id="couns"><?php echo var4 ?></span>

<style>
    // let all the responses be hidden initially
    .response {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleResponse (id) {
        // hide any responses that might be showing
        $('.response').hide();
        // show the response for this option
        $('#' + id).show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a really non-DRY solution that gets ugly in a hurry with more packages.

Comment: Which makes it basically my answer, but changes his HTML structure ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the quickest and easiest way to do it.

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/te36zy18/

HTML

```
<p>
<label for="package" class="formlbl">I want to Enroll In:</label>
    <select name="package" id="package">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="full_package">Complete Package</option>
    <option value="training">Only Training</option>
    <option value="counselling">Only Counselling</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div id="full_package" class="package"><?php echo full_package;?></div>
<div id="training" class="package"><?php echo training;?></div>
<div id="counselling" class="package"><?php echo counselling;?></div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#package").on("change", function(){
  var package = $(this).val();
  $(".package").hide()
  $("#" + package).show();
});
```

CSS

```
.package {display: none'}
```